# Posting data/form using j query in asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to post my form/ partial view using j query in asp.net MVC.

I am doing this. First I am preventing my form submission to check custom validation in my form, Validation is working fine but form is not posting.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#myModal").on("submit", "form", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            debugger;
            var selectedindex = $(".ddlVendor").prop('selectedIndex');
            var orderQuantity = $(".txtOrderQuantity").val();

            if (selectedindex <= 0) {
                $(".lblmsg").html("Select Vendor First");
                $(".lblmsg").show();
            }
            else if (!jQuery.trim(orderQuantity).length > 0) {
                $(".lblmsg").html("Please Enter Order Quantity");
                $(".lblmsg").show();
            }
            else {
                $.ajax({

                    method: "POST",  
                    url: '<%= Url.Action("GenratePO", "Order") %>',  
                    data: 
                    { //Passing data  
                        VendorId: $(".ddlVendor").val(),
                        FabricId: $(".ddlFabric").val(),
                        Address: $("#txtOrderQuantity").val(),
                        OrderId: $("#orderId").val()
                    }

                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: "Validation is working fine but form is not posting"...ok, but what happens instead? Which path does your code take? Does it enter into the `else` block where the $.ajax() code is? Does that ajax request begin? Do you get any kind of response from the server? You can look in your browser's developer tools (console, code and network sections) to debug all of this, which really you could/should have done before posting the question, then we can get some proper detailed information about the situation, not just a vague "it's not working".

Comment: what do you think i have not tested this things, no error message in console, in the ajax resquest i noticed one thing url is showing undefined and i don't know why.

Comment: Is this a typo (The '.' before '#')?  OrderId: $(" **.#** orderId").val()

Comment: @Sychal its a typing mistake bro. i changed this in my question.

Comment: @Bhupendra - why do you need to do an ajax post if the validation is successful? If you have a submit button on on your form then the post and form serialization has already been done. You should only preventDefault if your validation fails.

Comment: well sorry but you never mentioned what you'd tested...saying "not working" is usually an indication of not having done any debugging. It's true of many questions on SO, unfortunately. We can't read your mind, so if you've done it, you should say it. Anyway that's more useful info now...so the URL is undefined, I guess your URL.Action is not working properly then. Is this code within a View?

Comment: @Wheels73 i did it as you say, i am preventing the form submission only when the  validation failed, but thinking why the fuck i have not think this. well thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @ADyson its working now with some different logic, but thanks for suggestiong i will mention the proper information and detail next time. thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: @Bhupendra - ha ha...yeah.. we all think that sometimes! Glad its sorted